# while loop not showing correctly in google chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, console.log

I want to show up all numbers between -10 and 19 but my google chrome  console returning me just one number in while loop. what is the solution of this  problem? 
 any idea? how can i  solve this problem?

```
console.log("i want to print all numbers between -10 to 19");
var counter=-10;
while(counter < 20) { console.log(counter); counter++; }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: can you show your code so we can help you ?

Comment: console.log("i want to print all numbers between -10 to 19");
 var counter=-10;
 while(counter < 20){
  console.log(counter);
  counter++;
 }

Comment: i have also uploaded  a screenshot

Comment: it works for me in chrome

Comment: did you see the screenshot i've uploaded? @RobertNegreanu

Comment: no, I can't find

Comment: please check this out https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIYXw.png @RobertNegreanu

Comment: Change your filter from "Errors" to "Info" ;)

Comment: thank you . it worked. :) @RobertNegreanu

Answer (score 0):

Change your filter level. You can use "**Info**" or "**Verbose**" but not "Warnings" and "Errors"